# BitmapImage PixelWidth and PixelHeight property from UriSource

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have this:

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
bi.UriSource = new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

,where url =www.xyz.com/abc.jpg

My question is "How to get the bi.PixelWidth and bi.PixelHeight?" because both are coming as zero. I want to resize big images in to thumbnails.

I have tried this [one](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/12/17/silverlight-s-big-image-problem-and-what-you-can-do-about-it.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly new to WP7 development. I cam across this issue and is actually still trying to figure out how to do this.

But I could get it to work with `WritableBitmap` like so :

```
Uri uri = new Uri("/image.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmapImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
bitmapImage.UriSource = uri;
WriteableBitmap img = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage);

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    // write an image into the stream
    Extensions.SaveJpeg(img, ms, img.PixelWidth, img.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
    byte[] byteArray = ms.ToArray();
}
```